# Exposed filters drop down select translated but not displaying on view

Tags: views, i18n-l10n

The field items are properly translated but they don't show up in the views exposed filters.

Can be seen over here on the French page:

can be seen here:  http://sandbox.vuxi.com/fr/node?qt-qt_index_search_b_a_u=1#qt-qt_index_search_b_a_u

Answer (score 0):

For translating exposed filters, you need to enable all translation modules FIRST. And THEN create your views.

Because there is a multilingual option to pick filters, the translatable one.

User: Example (field_example:language) (translated)
Language - Appears in: user:user.

So if you want a multilingual site, install all translation modules FIRST, and then create your views with multiple filters.